# Eclipse Install Software via command line fails with "JVM terminated. Exit code=13"

Tags: eclipse, activiti

Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) on Ubuntu 14.04

I try to install Activiti Designer in Eclispe via command line:

```
eclipse -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://activiti.org/designer/update/ -destination /usr/lib/eclipse -installIU org.activiti.designer.feature.feature.group
```

This fails as follows:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 400001
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director
-repository http://activiti.org/designer/update/
-destination /usr/lib/eclipse
-installIU org.activiti.designer.feature.feature.group
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

The installation via *Help > Install New Software* is working as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This line looks a little suspicious `-vm /usr/bin/java`

Can you check for that in eclipse.ini - those values should be on separate lines, e.g.

```
-vm
/usr/bin/java
```

as mentioned in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: The eclipse.ini does not have the -vm option'-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
'

But it seems I simply forgot to _sudo_...